# Record the time that the element is present on screen

Tags: python, selenium, appium, appium-android

I have a code to test an app, and I need to record the time that the progress bar is present on the page. I have an idea in mind with a while loop and try-except, but I am afraid it might be inaccurate due to the possible delays with finding an element function. Any ideas? Python preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize a `creation_time` variable right before your element appears on the screen, and then a `destory_time` variable right after your element gets destoryed.

```
from datetime import datetime

# REST OF THE CODE

creation_time = datetime.now()

# ......

destroy_time = datetime.now()

appearance_time = destory_time - creation_time
```

Answer (score 0):

This may have been your thought but I'd try using EC.visibility_of_element_located in a while loop. When the element is first located, store the time in a variable as the above answer suggests. Then when the element is no longer visible, store the time in another variable and stop the loop